# WCF Streaming across proxy servers etc

Tags: wcf, proxy, streaming

All

Sorry if this is an obvious question but does WCF streaming work correctly from a client to an web server (using basicHttpBinding) if a proxy server is in the way?

I seem to remember reading that proxy servers can cache requests until they are ready (hence why sometimes a download doesn't respond for ages then suddenly completes) and I'm not sure if this will stop streaming working correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably too late for you, but from my interpretation of the web page below- no, streaming does not work when a proxy server is in the way.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx

> The decision to use either buffered or streamed transfers is a local decision of the endpoint. For HTTP transports, the transfer mode does not propagate across a connection or to proxy servers and other intermediaries. Setting the transfer mode is not reflected in the description of the service interface. After generating a WCF client to a service, you must edit the configuration file for services intended to be used with streamed transfers to set the mode. For TCP and named pipe transports, the transfer mode is propagated as a policy assertion.